# Is "performance" a common word in spanish IT terminology?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

While reading [a spanish-language article](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/editorial/animaciones-2d-con-video-en-canvas-html5/) on some client-side topics,
I was surprised to read following passage:

> La gente de Microsoft hizo un excelente artículo (con una gran demo incluida), donde se pueden apreciar las ventajas que ofrece este método **en términos de performance**.

My question is - Is performance a common, well established word in spanish IT slang, which is used instead of "rendimiento" or whatever is used in standard Spanish in that cases?

If yes, this is appropriate, then how should I pronounce it?

Comment: It is very common but you also have: desempeño, rendimiento, duración and comportamiento, But each of these words have it's own meaning while at the same time they share some similarities. You also have Performar but is less used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common to spot it through the Latin American IT world, though it is not correct, as the proper word for that is, as you say, "rendimiento", or "comportamiento". There is no excuse to use "performance" in Spanish.

My guess is that people who use "performance" understand the concept but don't link it the word in Spanish for that. The pronunciation would be similar as in English, "performans".

Comment: As a side note, "performance" is becoming really common for "street performances" instead of "representación callejera".

Comment: [Google ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=performance%2C+rendimiento%2C+comportamiento&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=10&smoothing=3) shows that 'performance' came into usage in the early 1960s, but is still rarely used. 'comportamiento' is easily the favored term.

Comment: Well, that's when computers started to become a little bit more popular, out from calculus/military context.

Answer (score 3):

I would say not really, at least in Spain.

I am Computer Engineer, and I think most of us would understand it, but is not a common term.

This is totally subjective. though, but to me it sounds a bit ridiculous, even... Like you'd be trying to be "cool".

If you were to pronounce it, I'm guessing the phonetic transcription would be: peɾfoɾ´manθe (I just used an [online tool](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=es&langpair=en%7Ces&u=http://project-modelino.com/online-resources-category.php?site_language=english&learn_language=spanish&category=text_converters), though)